# Помогите найти файл от битрикса, отвечающий за свойства

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно найти файл, отвечающий за свойства ? Ситуация такая, что на этой странице [http://купить-трубу-спб.рф/products/1/41/](http://%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1.%D1%80%D1%84/products/1/41/) мне нужно изменить структуру, мне нужно чтобы на страницах детального просмотра товара не было никаких фотографий и прочего. Чтобы было только описание+ценники, как на скриншоте - http://radikal.ru/big/8ow4n39qq86gk . Когда я нажимаю на странице посмотреть код , то вижу классы, около трёх, которые нужно закомментировать, но когда захожу через ftp, я эти файлы просто не могу найти, файлы с классами этими..... Может кто-то сталкивался или знает решение проблемы....

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. Копируем шаблон элемента, далее редактируем его, вот инструкция - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04778&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565.4790.4778

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, настроена переадресация в файле корень/urlrewrite.php. Надо найти правило, которое переписывает /products/, в нем написано в какой папке лежит основной файл.

Если в коде страницы вы видите что-то типа

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list", "reviews", Array(
"IBLOCK_TYPE" => "news",    // Тип инфоблока
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "5",     // Инфоблок
    ......
```

и вы ищете, где это правится, то файлы, которые выводят этот компонент на страницу могут находиться:

```
1. /bitrix/components/bitrix/news.list/templates/reviews (если вместо "reviews" 
стоит "", то .default)

если там нет, то

2. /bitrix/templates/ название_вашго_шаблона_англ /components/bitrix/news.list/reviews

если там нет, то

3. /bitrix/templates/ название_вашго_шаблона_англ /components/bitrix/news.list/reviews
```

файл называется template.php.

Бывает еще папка local, но это если какая-то компания предоставляла готовый сайт.